# Contar numero de registros de una tabla A revisando un valor contenido B

Tags: php, mysql

Tengo una pregunta sobre como contar el numero de registros de la tabla TUTOR basandome en el tipo de carrera al cual pertenece un PROYECTO.

Esto debido a que deseo conocer cuantos tutores estan en proyectos de sistemas, de agronomia, de enfermeria, en fin.

Posee 3 tablas:

1. TUTOR: posee cedu_tuto
2. PROYECTO: posee proy_id y proy_carr_id(tipo de carrera antes mencionada)
3. PROYECTO_TUTOR: posee proy_id , tuto_id y proy_tuto_id

¿Cómo haría el select de la base de datos para que me cuente cuantos tutores están en proyectos cuyo `proy_carr_id` sea 1, sea 2 y sea 3?

La tabla anidada de PROYECTO y TUTOR es un enlace entre ambos.

Sé que se usaría un `LEFT JOIN` pero no recuerdo en que forma

hasta ahora va algo asi:

```
function bd_rep23()
{
    $sql = "SELECT  COUNT(*) FROM tutor where cedu_tuto 
            LEFT JOIN proyecto c ON a.tuto_id = c.carr_id
            ORDER BY a.cedu_tuto ASC";
    $id=sql2value($sql);
    return $id;
}
```

No sé si deba antes seleccionar los datos y luego contar

#### Estructura de las tablas

TUTOR:

```
CREATE TABLE `tutor` (
    `cedu_tuto` int(9) UNSIGNED NOT NULL COMMENT 'CÃ©dula',
    `ape1_tuto` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
    `ape2_tuto` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
    `nom1_tuto` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
    `nom2_tuto` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
    `telf_resi_tuto` varchar(11) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
    `telf_celu_tuto` varchar(11) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
    `proy_id` int(4) NOT NULL,
    `tipo_id` int(1) NOT NULL,
    `emai_tuto` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
```

PROYECTO:

```
CREATE TABLE `proyecto` (
    `proy_id` int(4) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    `proy_deno` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
    `plan_proy` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
    `objg_proy` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
    `obje_proy` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
    `fech_insc` date NOT NULL,
    `nomb_comu` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
    `resp_comu` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
    `parr_id` int(4) NOT NULL,
    `deta` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
    `esta_proy_id` int(1) NOT NULL,
    `telf_inst` varchar(11) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
    `telf_resp` varchar(11) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
    `obsv_proy` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
    `proy_carr_id` int(2) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
```

PROYECTO_TUTOR:

```
CREATE TABLE `proyecto_tutor` (
    `proy_tuto_id` int(4) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    `proy_id` int(4) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    `tuto_id` int(9) UNSIGNED NOT NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
```

#### Formulario de la lista

```
<?php
include 'conexion.php';
$tutor=bd_rep3();
$tutora=bd_rep5();
$tutoraca=bd_rep21();
$tutorcomu=bd_rep22();
$tutormeto=bd_rep23();
$tutoring=bd_rep24();
include 'cab.php';
?>
<h2>Reporte de Cantidades</h2>
<table  class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover">
<thead>
        <tr>
        <th><center>Tutores</th>
        <th><center>Tutores Asignados</th>
        <th><center>Tutores Academicos</th>
        <th><center>Tutores Comunitario</th>
        <th><center>Tutores Metodológico</th>
        <th><center>Tutores en Ing.Sistemas</th>
        <th><center>Tutores en Ing.Gas</th>
        <th><center>Tutores en Educación</th>
        <th><center>Tutores en Administración</th>
        <th><center>Tutores en Ing.Agronoma</th>
        <th><center>Tutores en Enfermería</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>    
<tr>

        <td><?=$tutor?></td> 
        <td><?=$tutora?></td> 
        <td><?=$tutoraca?></td> 
        <td><?=$tutorcomu?></td> 
        <td><?=$tutormeto?></td> 
       <td><?=$tutoring?></td> 
                  </tr>    
</tbody>
</table>
<?php
include 'pie.php';
```

Siendo bd_rep24().

```
function bd_rep24()
{
    $sql = "SELECT proy_carr_id, COUNT(DISTINCT tuto_id)
            FROM PROYECTO_TUTOR pt
            LEFT JOIN PROYECTO p
              ON pt.proy_id = p.proy_id
            GROUP BY proy_carr_id";
            $id=sql2value($sql);
            return $id;
}
```

Parte del codigo de conexion.php, este contiene algunas funciones para transformar las querys a enteros, entre otros.

```
<?php
 $m = new mysqli(
'localhost',
'root',
'',
'proyecto_base'
);
if ($m->connect_errno)
{
printf("(lrcrud) Falló conexión: %s\n", $mysqli->connect_error);
exit();
}

$m->query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");

function sql($sql)
{
global $m;
$resultado = $m->query($sql);
if ( $resultado === FALSE )
{
    printf( "%s\n", $m->error );
    exit;
}
return $resultado;
}

function sqlerror($sql,$error)
{
return "<html><head></head><body><ul>"
    ."<li>Instruccion SQL:<br /><pre>{$sql}</pre></li>"
    ."<li>Error SQL: <font color='red'>{$error}</font></li>"
    ."</ul></body></html>";
}

function sql2array($sql)
{
global $m;
if ( !$res=$m->query($sql) )
{
  echo sqlerror( $sql,$m->error );
  exit;
}
$r=array();
while( $temp=$res->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC) )
{
   $r[]=$temp;
}
return $r;
}

function sql2row($sql)
{
global $m;
if ( !$res=$m->query($sql) ) 
{
    echo sqlerror( $sql,$m->error );
    exit;
}
return $res->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
}

function sql2value($sql)
{
global $m;
if ( !$res=$m->query($sql) )
{
    echo sqlerror( $sql,$m->error );
    exit;
}
$p=$res->fetch_array(MYSQLI_NUM);
return $p[0];
}

function sql2options($sql)
{
global $m;
if ( !$res=$m->query($sql) )
{
  echo sqlerror( $sql,$m->error );
  exit;
}
$r=array();
while( $l=$res->fetch_array(MYSQLI_NUM) )
{
   $r[$l[0]]=$l[1];
}
return $r;
}

function sqlexist($id,$tabla)
{
global $m;
$sql="SELECT COUNT(*) FROM $tabla WHERE id = '$id'";
if (sql2value($sql)>0)
{
  return TRUE;

}
else
{
  return FALSE;
}
}

function sqlexistvct($valor,$campo,$tabla) {
global $m;
$sql="SELECT COUNT(*) FROM $tabla WHERE $campo = '$valor'";
if (sql2value($sql)>0)
{
  return TRUE;
}
else
{
  return FALSE;
}
}

function cifra_clave($clave,$sal)
{
return sha1($clave.$sal);
}
```

Luego seguirian las funciones para agregar editar y borrar, alumnos, tutores y proyectos.

Quiero mostrar asi:
Tutores de sistemas: 4
turores de administracion: 4
tutores de agronomia: 4
cada uno en una columna de la lista que esta comenzando la pregunta.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Para contar la cantidad de registros que no están duplicados, se usa `DISTINCT`. Incluso, se puede utilizar dentro de COUNT, como `COUNT(DISTINCT columna)`. Y esto lo usaremos agrupando por carrera con `GROUP BY carr_id`.

#### Query

```sql
SELECT carr_id id, COUNT(DISTINCT tuto_id) cant
FROM PROYECTO_TUTOR pt
LEFT JOIN PROYECTO p
  ON pt.proy_id = p.proy_id
GROUP BY carr_id
```

**Ejemplo de resultado**

```
+---------+-------------------------+
|      id |                    cant |
+---------+-------------------------+
|       1 |                       2 |
|       2 |                       2 |
|       3 |                       1 |
+---------+-------------------------+
```

<kbd>[Demo en SQLfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e47abc/2/0)</kbd>

---

#### Código

Para llamar a la función:

```php
$tutoresCarrera = bd_rep24();
```

En `bd_rep24` deberías obtener el `array` (no el valor).

```php
function bd_rep24()
{
    $sql = "SELECT proy_carr_id id, COUNT(DISTINCT tuto_id) cant
            FROM PROYECTO_TUTOR pt
            LEFT JOIN PROYECTO p
              ON pt.proy_id = p.proy_id
            GROUP BY proy_carr_id";
    $id=sql2array($sql);
    return $id;
 }
```

Y luego, para construir el la tabla en el HTML:

```php
<tbody>    
  <tr>
    <td><?=$tutor?></td> 
    <td><?=$tutora?></td> 
    <td><?=$tutoraca?></td> 
    <td><?=$tutorcomu?></td> 
    <td><?=$tutormeto?></td>
    <?php
        foreach ($tutoresCarrera as &$fila) {
            echo '<td>' . $fila['cant'] . '</td>';
        } 
    ?>
  </tr>    
</tbody>
```

Comment: @Victor Este query hace exactamente eso, te devuelve la consulta cuántos tutores hay para cada `carr_id`. En el ejemplo que puse muestra 2 tutories para Sistemas, 2 tutores para Agronomía, 1 para Enfermería.

Comment: El query ya lo tenés resuelto, te falta resolver cómo recorrer la tabla devuelta, imprimiendo los valores en PHP

Comment: @Victor Quizás estás equivocado. No soy un profesor particular. Buscá información en la web e intentá ser más preciso en las preguntas. Publiqué una respuesta, espero que te sirva (yo ya no tengo más tiempo para dedicarle).

Comment: se puede aplicar este metodo tambien para valores de ID pero que no esten anidados?